# Selenium execute test cases from remote machine

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am executing Selenium test cases on a remote machine using microsoft VSTS release pipeline "Run Powershell on target machine", this powershell script is running properly on local machine, but when trying to execute on remote machine, always getting the error, "**Starting ChromeDriver 2.32.498550 (9dec58e66c31bcc53a9ce3c7226f0c1c5810906a) on port 42936, only local connections are allowed**"

Please let me know how to resolve the issue.

Comment: it seems just a message not a error. is your remote machine linux or any other os?

Comment: remote machine is windows

Comment: you also can see it when you run on local. it's not an error. If this  is your concern,  leave it go.

Comment: Is there any failure of test or not? If not then this is not what you should worry about

Comment: Yes the execution is failing